# Boxing Micro Rings

Tags: training, technique, boxing, equipment

I have seen a few micro rings posted around mainly one by trojanfit.

http://www.trojanfit.co.uk/trojanfit-micro-boxing-ring-1362-p.asp

I think the idea is to train in an area where you aren't able to run and therefore have to focus on blocking. Also it would get you used to being against the ropes, so you don't feel pressured in that situation.

The price range is in the same ballpark as any other big bit of kit for a home gym, and i'de be able to fit it in my garage. (there are a couple of gyms I found that have them, but not close enough for me to justify trying it out)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuCEcxU-qo0

Has anyone in the community trained using a micro ring? Did you find that it helped improve your technique?

Comment: never seen them before but they make too much sense to not exist. Are these things new, or they have been around for a while?

Comment: it seems to be a trojanfit thing they started doing in the last year. not sure if its the only one, but its the only one i've been able to find.

Comment: sometimes we train in regular ring, split in two halves by plain piece of rope. In every half there are two fighters. Sparring that way you have limited maneuver space (still you can "bend" rope a bit) so you can focus more on your offense/defense technique. IMHO Buying special "micro" ring seems like a waste of money

Comment: It may be that it is geared towards home gyms or maximizing space in a gym, i know i cant fit a full sized ring in a garage or spare room.

Answer (score 2):

I have done training that mirrors a micro ring (though I can't see a gym actually wasting space on one of these). Two of the most effective were:

**King of the Square:**

The mats at my gym are in squares. We pick a square that's probably around 8x8, so the same as that micro ring (which has a fight space of 9x9). You're not allowed to leave the square for the duration of the drill (usually 2 minutes), and the goal is to be in the center of the square more than your opponent. It helps you to work on dirty boxing, switching between head and body shots, and knees and elbows if we're MMA sparring. I find this kind of sparring very effective, as it causes guys that are typically outside strikers to get in the range that they're not comfortable with.

**King of the Corner:**

Similar to King of the Square, but you're using a corner of the gym. There's a set area of the walls that you have to stay within. The goal is to force your opponent out of the "square", to the opposite side of the corner. It's very difficult, as if you want to "win" the drill, you have to put your back to the wall and fight out of it. It goes against all intuition.

Both of these methods can be done with Boxing, Kickboxing, and MMA sparring. Rather then spend money and space on this specialty tool, use what you have. Squares and corners! Also prepare to get your liver crushed.

Answer (score -4):

Micro ring? Look, sounds to me like it's made for bare-knuckle fighting. Look up bare knuckle fighting in the UK on YouTube. They fight in tiny "rings" with no gloves. Some guys use hand-wraps, but they can't call themselves real bare knuckle fighters.

Comment: Hi @Clementino, welcome to the site. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a general discussion. Please post actual answers and refrain from leaving opinion and/or general chit-chat on each question you read. Make sure you take [the tour](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) and understand it before answering. Thanks!